# Draw a circle in a Canvas using changing-variable(animation)

Tags: java, android, variables, canvas, draw

Bonjour!

I m a beginner.
I would like to draw a corcle with this code but it doesn t work.It doesn t send me an error but it draws nothing :( .

```
float width = this.getWidth(), height = this.getHeight();//Ns permet de savoir la resolution
//
float posXj=(width/2), posYj=(height-50);//position de depart du joueur
//
boolean dGauche=false,dDroite=false;//d=deplacement

//------------------Dessine Le Joueur------------------
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

//canvas.;
Paint pPrincipal = new Paint();
pPrincipal.setAntiAlias(true);

pPrincipal.setColor(Color.parseColor("#778899"));
canvas.drawCircle(this.posXj,this.posYj,25,pPrincipal );

}
//--------------FIN:Dessine Le Joueur------------------
```

I know that the problem come from this:

```
float width = this.getWidth(), height = this.getHeight();
```

It doesn t return the width an height of the screem.
But i need to write this variable like this because,after i would like to do a basic animation with my circle.

Thank you for your help guys.
Salut!

PS:Sorry for my english i m french ;)

Comment: @mona //Hi thk you for your help!But sorry,I didn t understand your question?

Comment: OK i Found the solution it was very easy.I have to write this:

     private float width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();//Ns permet de savoir la resolution


instead of this:

float width = this.getWidth(), height = this.getHeight();//Ns permet de savoir la resolution

Comment: /////////
Hom can i write the question "solve" thk you

Comment: @Mona//Do it for me pls because me if i want to post my answer i need to wait 9hours.So pls cpoy -colly my answer and post it it will be cool ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private float width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()
height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
//Ns permet de savoir la resolution instead of this: 
float width = this.getWidth()
height = this.getHeight();//Ns permet de savoir la resolution
```